# combining different beliefs about an unknown quantity

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a question about combining beliefs but I am not sure I am thinking about this problem correctly.

There is a bag containing an unknown number of balls.  Person A believes that there is a 50% chance that the bag contains 10 balls and a 50% chance that it contains a different number of balls.  Person B believes that there is a 75% chance that the bag contains 20 balls and a 25% chance that the bag contains a different number of balls.  I place equal trust these two beliefs.

Am I correct to say that given a set of different beliefs about the value of an unknown quantity then the strength of each belief conditional upon the other beliefs (assuming that they are equally trusted) is simply the relative strength of each belief to the other beliefs weighted by the strength of the belief itself?

(Excuse my notation)

$Bel(A|B) = Bel(A) * Bel(A) / (Bel(A)+Bel(B))$

I therefore believe that there is a 20% chance that the bag contains 10 balls, a 45% chance that the bag contains 20 balls and a 35% chance that it contains a different number of balls.  This seems to make intuitive sense but I am not sure this is a particularly sensible way combining beliefs, it doesn't seem to involve updating probabilities in any kind of Bayesian sense.

Any help clarifying this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: This seems vague.  If nothing else, we'd need to know something about the probability $A$ assigns to $20$ and the probability $B$ assigns to $10$.

Comment: I guess that in the limit of there being any possible number of balls in the bag, these tend to zero.

Comment: It's your problem.  If you want to assume that those probabilities are $0$, you should add that in.  It matters, as those two cases correspond to "both $A,B$ being right" in some sense of the term,

Comment: [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123793/combining-subjective-probability-estimates-and-statistical-estimates-for-forecas) is a discussion of a related issue.

Comment: Hi Lulu, thanks, see below, I think I was heading off in the wrong direction earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have been a bit foolish here.  If we assume that the bag may contain between 1 and 100 balls, then person A is implying a probability mass function with value 0.5 at n=10 and 0.5/99 at all other values. Person B is implying a probability mass function with value 0.75 at n=20 and 0.25/99 at all other values.

Adding these two mass functions together and normalizing gives a probability mass function with two peaks representing the combined belief assuming equal weighting. This implies a roughly 25% chance that the bag contains 10 balls and 37.5% chance that the bag contains 20 balls with the remaining mass (1-(0.25+0.375)) distributed over the other values.

I am not sure what I was thinking earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You propose an ad-hoc approach of weighting two pmfs. Since this problem deals with degree of belief, Bayes theorem is useful. In so doing, one needs to assume that person A and person B are rational. If you believe them to be irrational then the information they provide is of unknown value for the problem.

Given that A and B are rational, they came to their stated degrees of belief by making different observations ($x_A$ and $x_B$). Without more information, it is safe to assume that they had the same prior belief (equal probability for the 100 outcomes). A and B both use Bayes theorem to make that calculation, for example for any value $n$, its probability is stated by person A to be:
$$P(n|x_A)=P(x_A|n)P(n)/P(x_A)$$

To combine information from two observations (assumed independent), use the combined likelihood:
$$P(n|x_A,x_B)=cP(x_A,x_B|n)P(n)=c_1P(x_A|n)P(x_B|n)P(n)$$

where $c_1$ is a normalization constant. Given the assumption of uniform prior it is easy to see that
$$P(n|x_A,x_B)=c_2P(n|x_A)P(n|x_B)$$
so instead of adding the pmfs and renormalizing, you should be multiplying the pmfs and renormalizing. This makes sense, since if A's degree of belief for $n=13$ is zero, then there is no possibility that $n=13$.
Using this approach:
$P(10)=20.0\%$, $P(20)=60.0\%$, and for the rest $P=0.20\%$.

Comment: Hi Dean, thanks for your explanation.  However, something that doesn’t sit comfortably with me is the notion that, hypothetically, if A believes that there is no possibility of there being 13 balls in the bag then this multiplicatively negates any belief that B has about the number of balls being 13. Any conditional probability that A assigns, other than zero, to a number of balls being in the bag will allow B to express (to some degree) their belief in the posterior probability.  The ability of A to act as gate keeper over B’s belief doesn’t seem right.

Comment: @John, your comment suggests that you do not trust the assessments of A or B - as I stated, both A and B are assumed to be rational. If the A observation yeilds P(hypothesis)$=0$, there is nothing that the B observation yields P(hypothesis)$\ne0$. But you get to combine A and B data and will rationally conclude that P(hypothesis)$=0$. If you want to introduce the idea that A and B may report pmfs that do not arise from rational calculations, then you need to specify the probability that the various wrong pmfs would be reported in order to work out the posterior pmf. Suggest googling Bayes.

Comment: am I correct to state in layman’s terms that if I only believe what person A is claiming C% of the time I could simply write $P(n|x_A)=C*P(x_A|n)P(n)/P(x_A)+(1-C)*P(n)$ implying that 75% of the time I simply defer to the prior distribution of n.  Is this an effective way of capturing the confidence I place in each observers claim? Thanks again for your comments

Comment: @John... I am not convinced you have carefully read/understood my comments. You seem to insist that if A and B report different pmfs, then it is because one or both are "wrong". This is a fundamentally incorrect way to interpret degrees of belief based on logical conclusions from observations. When A and B report degrees of belief for various hypotheses, it is not necessary to introduce arbitrary weights to the two peoples statements. You are convolving a problem involving degrees of belief about the number of balls with degrees of belief for the honesty of A and B. Ending this thread now.

Comment: once again, thanks for your input and apologies for my failure to grasp the basics here.  I think I need to rephrase my question and perhaps start another thread, but essentially, what strategy should I employ for including a degree of belief I have in the information provided by A & B? As you state, the application of Bayes assumes rational observers, but if this is not the case is there a more appropriate way of combining the 'beliefs' $P(n|x_A)$ and $P(n|x_B)$ when assigning a posterior distribution to the number of balls?